# Authentication code with expiration date code

Tags: go, sms, aws-sdk, go-gin

I have made go gin project

Using a technique such as twilio to send a 6-digit expiration date verification code to the user using the SMS sending function of aws sns.

When I try to implement a user-created function with a phone number and a six-digit authentication code, I don't come up with a good idea to implement a function that gives an expiration date to the authentication code.

Anyone have a good idea Do you know such a library?

Here is my source code I have created the logic up to creating a 6-digit authentication number

```
func GenerateAuthCode(max int) string {
    var table = [...]byte{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'}
    b := make([]byte, max)
    n, err := io.ReadAtLeast(rand.Reader, b, max)
    if n != max {
        return err.Error()
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        b[i] = table[int(b[i])%len(table)]
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

I want to generate in this logic

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any key-value store in your current architecture? If so, then you can use that to maintain the TTL for the generated auth code.

eg. In Redis, you can directly set the TTL for the keys. In other stores, where TTL is not supported inherently, you can just store the Unix timestamp of time till which the token is valid.

Comment: thanks, the comment I was going to store the information in MySQL
Do you know how to generate the auth code ??
I'd like you to let me know if there is something that is helpful

Comment: I guess MySQL can also serve fine. For the token generation, I guess you can just use the ```crypto``` package to generate random numbers securely. See
https://play.golang.org/p/BWQIEf0Pptj

Comment: You can use padding to fill the remaining digits if the length is less than six. I would suggest don't use constant padding, rather use the same function to generate digits with ```upper``` as 10.

Comment: Do I need such a table to create a function like otp?
Including information such as code access token expire

Comment: It depends on your use-case. You can easily use an in-memory map to store the data and avoid using any external storage (like tables or so). It will help to achieve lower latency but can result in scalability and performance issues, as you have to use a concurrent hashmap (or similar data structure). Also, garbage collection will be more frequent.

In your case, I will suggest to keep it simple, and go with a tabular approach (SQL based) and use indexes for faster scans. I think it should work just fine.